# Rewrite URL with htaccess (php)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm not the best with .htaccess so I hope someone here can help. I'm trying to rewrite a URL to look more clean.

Original URL: `domain.com/admin/users?userid=<id>`
What I want: `domain.com/admin/users/<id>`

I have tried this code but I'm getting a 404:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/users/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ users.php?userid=$1
RewriteRule ^admin/users/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ users.php?userid=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory was omitted from the rewrite. The character class can also be simplified and the trailing slash can be made optional:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/users/([-\w]+)/?$ admin/users.php?userid=$1
```

A detailed write up of `\w` can be found here, http://regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html. In short:

> \w stands for “word character”. It always matches the ASCII characters [A-Za-z0-9_]

regex101 can also be used, http://regex101.com/r/Px2vTE/1

Comment: Trying to write another URL, so the original URL is domain.com/admin/users-edit.php?userid=<id> and I want to rewrite it to domain.com/admin/users/<id>/edit

I've tried `RewriteRule ^admin/users/([-\w]+)/$/edit? admin/user-edit.php?userid=$1` but this won't work, any ideas why?

Comment: Got it working with `RewriteRule ^admin/users/([-\w]+)/edit/?$ admin/user-edit.php?userid=$1`